# Packet Tracer 8.1.1 doesn't luanch on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: 18.04, cisco

I have a DELL Latitude E6530 machine with the following specs:

[image: machine's specs]

I downloaded Packet Tracer 8.1.1 (.deb file) from https://netacad.com and after installing it, it didn't launch. I did some research and it turns out I had a problem with some shared libraries. I tried every way I know to install them, but did not work.

Can anyone help me please?

```
./PacketTracer: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by ./PacketTracer)
./PacketTracer: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./PacketTracer)
./PacketTracer: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1b' not found (required by ./PacketTracer)
./PacketTracer: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by ./PacketTracer)
    libQt5NetworkAuth.so.5 => not found
    libQt5WebSockets.so.5 => not found
    libQt5QmlModels.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Xml.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => not found
    libQt5TextToSpeech.so.5 => not found
```

Comment: Please do not show pictures when a couple lines of text can be placed in the body of the question.

Comment: A search of the site shows me many times this same question has been posted. From one of them this was a working answer have you tried this? sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5  and then the same for each of the missing dependencies.

Comment: Cisco packet tracer 8.1.1 is the 2022 version for a contemporary OS. .. If Ubuntu : Minimum = Ubuntu 20.04 ..... which has glibc-2.31 + gcc-9 with libstdc++ >= so.6.0.26 → GLIBCXX_3.4.26 . ...... For an old OS like 18.04, use older packet tracer version.

Comment: FWIW: with 8.1.1, the file `/usr/local/bin/packettracer` is a link to `/opt/pt/packettracer` which itself is a shell script with all output redirected to `/dev/null` (what a stupid idea!), so at first you don't see the above messages. You need to (sudo) edit that file and remove the redirection.